# Error: Call to a member function storeAs() on string

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-request

```php
public function cadastraAutomovelHomeAdd(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->arquivo;
    $upload = $request->arquivo->storeAs('products', 'novonomeaffffff.jpg');
    exit();
}
```

**Form**

```php
<form method='post' action='/cadastrar' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div>
        <h5>Placa do Veículo:</h5>
    </div>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name='arquivo' required placeholder="IMAGEM DO VEÍCULO">
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::post('/cadastrar','Automovel@cadastraAutomovelHomeAdd');
```

I submit the form, and I get the following error.

> Call to a member function storeAs() on string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap it as a file to access the file methods, something like:

`$upload = $request->file('arquivo')->storeAs('products', 'novonomeaffffff.jpg');`

https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: I don't understand Chris, please write the correct code for me? Please

Comment: I have, it is right there above? You had `->arquivo` but it should be `->file('arquivo')`

Comment: Cris your code error: Call to a member function storeAs() on null

Comment: Not my code mate. The above error though would suggest that `arquivo` doesn't contain any uploaded data, are you sure you are uploading a file? Trying dumping out the request data with something like `dump($request->all())`

Comment: "_token" => "AltCjFjNN3FfZU8xhdjSE9M5ki6bxnAnmStZhDW8"
  "arquivo" => "download.png"
  "placa" => "w"
  "marca" => "w"
  "modelo" => "e"
  "cor" => "f"
  "tipcombust" => "r"
  "nportas" => "4"
  "quilometragem" => "22"
  "renavam" => "wqdqw"
  "chassi" => "wqd"
  "valordiaria" => "222"
]

Comment: after error again: "Call to a member function storeAs() on null"

Comment: $request->file('arquivo'); IS NULL. The method file() , its necessary some library????

Comment: Relax. People are here trying to help in their own spare time... `file` is not part of an external library (it is part of laravel, please take 30mins to read through the docs I linked above). It seems your request isn't treating the file as a file, are you sure the form is set to multipart? Please update your question with your full controller method code and also the full form you are creating

Comment: Ok, its work, i created a new view with  a new form e and its all right.

Comment: Are All Right!! Thanks, but my english is not very well